# How to pass XSLT parameter with maven-xml-plugin?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, maven-plugin

This is a piece of my xslt 2.0 file:

```
<xsl:template match="test-one">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="document('../test.xml')//class"/>
</xsl:template>
```

As it is seen path `../test.xml` is hard coded. Now I want to pass path as parameter using xml-maven-plugin. So I do:

```
<transformationSet>
    <dir>src/test/resources</dir>
    <includes>foo.xml</includes>
    <stylesheet>xslfile.xsl</stylesheet>
    <parameters>
        <parameter>
          <name>path</name>
          <value>../test.xml</value>
        </parameter>
    </parameters>
    <outputDir>${project.build.directory}/test-classes/META-INF</outputDir>
</transformationSet>
```

However, I can't understand how to add this path to xslt file. I tried:

```
<xsl:template match="test-one">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="document('$path')//class"/>
</xsl:template>
```

But it didn't work. Could anyone say how to do it?

Comment: It is not clear whether you have declared `<xsl:param name="path"/>` in your XSLT. If you have, you can use `document($path)`. But it is also not clear to me whether you want to use Maven parameters or XSLT ones.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Look, I have a XSLT (like a function). And I want to pass to it one parameter - parameter `path`. I use XSLT file using `maven-xml-plugin`, so it is clear, that this parameter I need to pass via parameters of this plugin (at least I understand so). I found this https://www.mojohaus.org/xml-maven-plugin/examples/transform-parameters.html so I added `<parameters>` to `<transformationSet>`. In XSLT I don't have `<xsl:param name="path"/>`. Should I add it?

Comment: For `document($path)` to make sense, yes, you need to declare the `<xsl:param name="path"/>` at the top level of the XSLT.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Yes, it helped! Thank you very much. If you make an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For XSLT, to use external parameters, you need to declare them at the top level, i.e. as children of `xsl:stylesheet` or `xsl:transform`: `<xsl:param name="path"/>`.